# How can I install an old version of Google Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have a specific requirement (probably silly!) for testing a browser of Chrome. I realize this requirement isn't the most logical, but politics being what they may I'd like to know the technical workaround.

I need to test a site in version, let's say, 28 of Google Chrome. Obviously Google runs a silent updater which can be disabled, but at this point they don't (to my knowledge) release old archives of the MSI installers (which I can easily use to reinstall and force a no-update option for testing). If we can get this working on a single instance then there's a possibility that a virtual machine or some other workaround will give us an easy restore point to meet this test.

If anyone has a good idea of where to start here that would be amazing.

I've already floated the **"why are we doing this question?"** and the answer is that it is part of the requirements so we need to make a best effort.

***UPDATE:***

- FileHippo appears to only archive the online installer (automatic
  update)
- OldApps doesn't archive Chrome anymore
- OldVersion doesn't
  appear to have any Chrome Archives

***UPDATE 2:***
 - The accepted answer's server is the correct solution here at this point in time. Basically speaking you're looking for the full install (30 or so MB). If you have an 800K file it is the online installer which automatically updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site http://www.go4it.ro/download/internet/google-chrome-28-11113372/ downloads a 33 MB file - can't check the version though without uninstalling and have not verified whether the site is trustworthy. Re-uploading to http://www.virustotal.com might be a good idea.

Found this by Googling another variation: chrome 28 download

Comment: These passed the security scan. Romanian appears to be the solution right now!

Answer (score 17):

*Taking [denilson-sá's answer](https://superuser.com/a/832485/474367) further...*

You need revision numbers to grab downloads. So first lookup the full version string from the following URL, adjusting parameters as needed:

https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/history.json?channel=stable&os=mac

For Chrome version 28 the full version string is 28.0.1500.71. Now go to https://omahaproxy.appspot.com and enter the full version string ("28.0.1500.71") into the Position Lookup box. Copy the Base Position number ("209842" in this case).

You can use that base position number and platform as a filter at either of these URLs:

- http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html
- http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html

You probably won't have a perfect match on the base position number but you can at least use it to get close to the version you want.

Comment: Excellent answer which helped me overcome a blockage, given that I needed to use an older version of Chrome to catter for deprecated function in newer versions.
More specifically, cannot get to display sitecore 6.5's modal windows in Chrome greater than v.36.

Comment: After doing this, I found I also had to set up a custom shortcut as described in step #4 at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785991/can-i-run-multiple-versions-of-google-chrome-on-the-same-machine-mac-or-window/10917231#10917231, or else Chromium would just hang on startup.

Comment: I have the same question for testing our product. That link contains chromium (not chrome). Do you know source link to download old version of chrome (not chromium)?

Comment: Most of mini_installer.exe are broken, they simply don't install anything runnable....

Answer (score 7):

You can try browsing from Chromium continuous build archives:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html

It has build numbers instead of version numbers. Still, at least this one is an official website, and it can be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a portable version you can try

- [Portable Chrome](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Google%20Chrome%20Portable/Additional%20Versions/) archive starting with version 8
- [Portable Chromium](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crportable/files/) archive starting with version 9

Comment: Good solution on Windows. No equivalent for Linux, is there?

Comment: Stops at v34 (2014-02-26)

Answer (score 1):

For Chromium Linux/Win/Mac: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bugazelle/chromium-all-old-stable-versions/master/chromium.stable.json

For Chrome - CentOS RPM: http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/RPMS/myrpms/google/

For Chrome - Debain/Ubuntu/Windows/Mac: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Answer (score 0):

You could just "Google" the version you are looking for...

I just put "v28 Google Chrome"

and got as a hit.
http://www.afterdawn.com/software/network/browsers/google_chrome_dev.cfm/v28_0_1500_20

UPDATE:
A Site for you:
http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php

found answer on this site (has been asked before):
https://superuser.com/questions/217913/where-can-i-download-specific-versions-of-google-chrome

Comment: No luck here, other than the downloads being empty (though I am behind a serious firewall right now). This (and all others) look like the chrome-installer.exe (800kb) as opposed to the ~ 30MB offline installer. The chrome-installer automatically updates to the latest version!

Comment: I've managed to find version 17...lol : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-frame/DQGveccMDsc  its about halfway down.

Comment: Close but no cigar! +1 for effort--I think we're barking up the wrong tree. But if someone finds more information that would be amazingly helpful.

Comment: did you spot the edit I made above?

Comment: I did, I need to update these answers. FileHippo is only serving the 800KBK installer (not the full offline) and OldApps "no longer supports chrome downloads"

Comment: maybe its the versions you tried on oldapps - the couple i tried worked fine

Comment: strange - went back and they no longer work :/ will investigate and get back to you

Comment: ok don't know what happened there. Perhaps would be easier if we knew all the versions you needed... found a v 23 if it helps - http://vimalpadsumbiya.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/google-chrome-23-offline-installer-free.html

Answer (score 0):

First, have the offline installer of Google Chrome v28. Next, disable your internet connection and open task manager, and in the processes tab, search and kill all GoogleUpdate.exe.

Second, open `Regedit` and go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER >> Software >> Wow6432Note`, under this right click and create key and name it `Google` and within Google, create a new key and name it `Update`. Within Update in the right panel, right click and create and name it `UpdateDefault`, (New >> DWORD (32-bit) / QWORD (64-bit)), and finally give it value 0.

Do the same thing under policy `HKEY_CURRENT_USER >> Software >> Policies`.

NOTE:

Don’t open both internet connection and “About Google Chrome” to check the version, as it will automatically update it to latest version.

To check it's version, you can use `wireshark`. Under the user-agent field, you will find the version of Google Chrome.

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

PortableApps.com seems to be the most trustworthy:

1. http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable
2. Right-click the Download Now button, and copy link address
3. Paste into notepad
4. Replace version (latest stable version by default) with the version you would like. You'll need to web-search to find the exact version you need (not just the major number)

So for v49: my link was:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/portableapps/GoogleChromePortable_49.0.2623.112_online.paf.exe?accel_key=69%3A1462408984%3Ahttp%253A//portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable%3A16fbdcd4%24036dc3c62c8d24ebca12b87e26a1e35e898ce6d5&click_id=53a3b914-125a-11e6-b81e-0200ac1d1d90&source=accel

I'm guessing that link will expire. But that link had v50... before, I changed it to 49.... and it worked for me today.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to search google for specific version https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+download+old+79+version
and then open on filepuma site,  https://www.filepuma.com/download/google_chrome_64bit_79.0.3945.79-24169/download/

Answer (score -1):

In this point in time, there is a Google help article about this - [Alternate (offline) Google Chrome installer (Windows)](https://support.google.com/installer/answer/126299?hl=en).

> If you're having problems downloading Chrome using the standard
>   installer at http://www.google.com/chrome, try downloading the browser
>   using an alternate installer, available through the links below.
>
> These alternate installers don’t require network connection to install
>   Chrome, so you can install Chrome while being offline. Once installed,
>   Chrome will attempt to automatically update whenever it detects that a
>   newer version of the browser is available. However, your network
>   configuration may prevent the browser from updating properly. It's
>   recommended that you bookmark this page and come back periodically to
>   manually download newer versions of Chrome. That way, you can be sure
>   to receive important security fixes and feature improvements. You can
>   see if updates are available by visiting the Google Chrome releases
>   blog.
>
> Choose between two alternate installers for Chrome:
>
> If you're downloading Chrome for your own user account only, use this
>   installer: [Alternate installer for one user account](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1).
>
> If you're downloading Chrome for all user accounts on your computer,
>   use this installer: [Alternate installer for all user accounts](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?system=true&standalone=1).
>
> After you've download the installer file you need, open the file and
>   follow the instructions on the screen to complete your installation.
>   For additional help, please visit the Chrome Help Center.

I'm not sure exactly what's the difference between the two installers offered above, but the two links do point to two different URLs. However, I have downloaded both of them, and compared them with a diff tool and they appear to be binarely same. Here are some details about current online and offline installer.

```
Current version of Chrome being 34.0.1847.131.

Online installer
File name: ChromeSetup.exe
Size: 863 kB (884 704 bytes)
File version: 1.3.23.9
SHA-1: 8BC28875E8B2D4327FF1CB11FC6337B95D5620D8

Offline installer
File name: ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe
Size: 36.6 MB (38 416 368 bytes)
File version: 1.3.21.115
SHA-1: 2393BAB7F408DC8D30F039FCA5D6B45600A0C4E7
```

If you must have an MSI file for installation in a corporate environment, or for your testing, try this URL:

https://www.google.com.au/chrome/business/browser/admin/

You can find more information here:

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/1628156?hl=en

Comment: You're correct here: the problem is Google doesn't release older versions which was the original reason I raised the question. The larger file is an offline installer. The other "auto updates".

Comment: When clicking on the download link for the offline installer I'm only redirected to the usual online installer. :( – I'm (currently) on MacOS X, though, maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: @zrajm Yes, that could be the cause. If you haven't found it yet, try the following link. It's a direct link for the latest, stable build DMG file for Mac. At this time it's approx. 64 MB so it should be the offline installer (or dmg image rather). I believe you will be able to use this same link to get new builds for Mac in the future (I expect the file size to grow). https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg